# How do I get a php value in Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hey guys I have this populated search form that will bring a table of people based on search result.  I need to be able to get the php variable that has the username I am trying to get, then that will get sent over to .php file using the JQuery UI which will open a notes window.

So here:

username, other, other , notes - this is a link and once clicked the following is called:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NotesAccessor").click(function () {

      alert(notes_name);
      run();
    });
    });
```

which leads to :

function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';
    showUrlInDialog(url);
}

to a function that opens the Jquery Dialog.

I need to access the username of the based notes that was clicked....if there was 20 results of different names, david, joe, john, etc... I click the notes with david as username, I need that to be sent over to the file that is opening so I can display the based notes on the appropriate username.

Here is my php:

```
.........
    <td>
        $csvusername
    </td>
.........
    <td>
    ";
      if ($checkNotes[1] == 'No')
    {
        echo "None";
    }
    if ($checkNotes[1] == 'Yes')
    {
            echo "<a href='#' id='NotesAccessor'>Click to access</a>";
    }
    echo "
    </td>
........
```

Let me know if this makes sense to you.  I am kinda stuck on this and could use a hand :)

David

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Comment: `<span id="cvusername">$cvusername</span>` `$('#cvusername').text()`

Comment: @boj if its a duplicate can I have all those likes?

Comment: @DavidBiga I don't understand what you mean. . .

Comment: @boj I was making a joke :)

Comment: So boj do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you use `<a href="#" data-user="xxx">click to access</a>`? That way you can use `$.fn.data('user')` to get the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what PHP variable you are trying to get, but generally, you can do:

```
<!-- /myScript.php?myVar=helloWorld -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myPhpVar = <?php echo $_GET['myVar']; ?>;
        alert(myPhpVar);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Beware of XSS attacks on user input and echoing without cleaning.

Comment: So using the $_GET['the php value I need to get]; I can get the value of the php value I want on the same page?

Comment: @user1477388  there is an issue with this,  I have not passed the value at all?  I am trying to get it.

Comment: @DavidBiga In order to "get" the value of $_GET, you have to put it in the query string.  So, if accessed the URL `/myScript.php?myVar=helloWorld` and used my code, you would get "helloWorld" output in an alert box via JavaScript.  To read more about retrieving client data via PHP, read http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php.

Comment: @span & @DavidBiga Yes, do not trust anything that a user gives you (anything that comes from the client).  You can usually get away with simply escaping special characters by using `<?php echo addslashes($_GET['myVar']); ?>` but you should consider looking up "php security" to use something even more secure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var x = '<?php echo $variable; ?>';
or
var x = '<?php echo my_function(); ?>'; 
</script>


<?php
function my_function()
{
  return $variable;
}
?>
```

this should do what you like :)